# Xamarin Android implementation of KeyedAppStatesReporter for app feedback

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I would like to implement app feedback from my xamarin android app to an EMM as described [here](https://developer.android.com/work/app-feedback/overview). It all starts with creating an instance of the KeyedAppStatesReporter class, which I don't know where to get from. I have also grepped the Xamarin monodroid-samples-master repo for "KeyedAppStatesReporter" without any success. What do I have to do in order to use KeyedAppStatesReporter in Xamarin.Android? Some magic Nuget package?

Any help appreciated,

--
Stefan

Comment: I searched KeyedAppStatesReporter. It need the `androidx.enterprise.feedback` package. I do not find in GitHub.  I would check again and feedback ASAP.

Comment: I did the same. No sign of KeyedAppStatesReporter. Should I file an issue in the xamarin android github repo? What do you suggest?

Comment: Still do not find it. You could post it in the link below. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues